# Weighted random number generation in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate a set of 100 random integers between a fixed range. One could be comprised of 100 numbers between 1 and 3, with specific probabilities of obtaining either 1, 2 and 3.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

See `?sample`.

For example:

```
sample(c(1, 2, 3), size = 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.4))
```

Comment: how about if the range between 1 to 20 and the probabilities of obtaining likes 18.7, 11,6. cannot list all the number, how to do it?