# Creating random binary matrices with different distributions

Tags: r, function, matrix, binary, probability

I have been recently helped in getting a function to write a random binary matrix, with the condition that the diagonal is 0s.

```
fun <- function(n){
  vals <- sample(0:1, n*(n-1)/2, rep = T)
  mat <- matrix(0, n, n)
  mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- vals
  mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- vals
  mat
}
```

Here I am entering values from the 'sample' to the upper and lower triangle separately. I would like to keep this in any updated function because sometimes I may wish to enter transpositions of each triangle into the other.

What I would like assistance with is how to change the frequency of 1s in the random matrix.  This already varies around, I believe, a normal distribution.  e.g. in a 9x9 matrix, there are 81-9=72 cells to fill, and the average number of 1s used is 36.

However, if I wanted to create matrices with a probability of e.g. p=0.9 of there being a 1, or e.g. p=0.2 of there being a 1... - how is this done?

I tried some ways of changing the sample(0:1,) part of the code by adding in probability functions but I only got errors.

Thanks

Comment: Changing the first line of the function to `vals <- sample(0:1, n*(n-1)/2, rep = T, prob=c(0.1,0.9))` works for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weighted random number generation in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899767/weighted-random-number-generation-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look in to **help page of `sample`** function

`?sample` shows :

> Usage
>
> sample(x, size, replace = FALSE, **prob = NULL**)

where

> **prob**
>   *A vector of probability weights for obtaining the elements of
>   the vector being sampled.*

and further below in **Details** you will see

> The optional prob argument can be used to give a vector of weights for
>   obtaining the elements of the vector being sampled. They need not sum
>   to one, but they should be non-negative and not all zero.

So to answer your question, apart from **read the manual** , use `prob=c(0.1,0.9)` if you want probability of 0.1 for first element of `x` and 0.9 for the second.